# My VS Code dont recognize the pip packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

Despite im used to program stuff, im new in Python so i decide to learn by myself.
So, i install VS code and python. At the moment i tryied to use stuff like *tensorflow*, is showing an error saying that **my imports are missing**.

I've already tryed to install everything again, search for a solution online and nothing worked.

If someone knows anything about how to fix this i'd be greatfull.

Comment: Could you please explain your problem in a bit more detail? Its hard to know what might be wrong based on what has been provided so far, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whether there are **multiple versions of python** in your environment, which will make the pip installed in one version of python instead of the python you are using.

Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the correct python. Then use `pip install packagename` to reinstall the package which you need.

Generally, we recommend people new to python to use the [conda virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments).

[image]

Comment: anaconda is simple to use?

Comment: It is more convenient and effective to manage the package, and the environment will not be disordered

Answer (score -2):

Confirm you have downloaded python correctly:

- Open terminal
- Run `python --version`

  - (if that doesn't work try `python3 --version`

Comment: i have python installed. 
In fact, i can program anything in python that dont require packages/lib's